# C# custom JSON Converter combing 2 examples I've found

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I couldn't come up with a good title for this.  Basically, I have some JSON coming back from an API proving to be poorly done and hard to deserialize. Originally I found a "JsonPathConverter" example to help decorate the class and the properties of the class to make deserialization work how I wanted it to on this JSON data. Then I ran into another issue where a part of the JSON is either a single object or an array of objects.  I found on here another example of how to do this "SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter" it looks at the JSON and if it's a single object makes it a list of that type.  Now I need both but just using both doesn't work you can't have one converter on the class and a different one on the properties.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to combine these two solutions into one JsonConverter solution.

JsonPathConverter.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GCRR
{
#nullable disable
    public class JsonPathConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties()
                                                    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
            {
                JsonPropertyAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                                .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                                                .FirstOrDefault();

                string jsonPath = (att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name);
                JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath);

                if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
                {
                    object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                    prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
                }
            }

            return targetObj;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // CanConvert is not called when [JsonConverter] attribute is used
            return false;
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
                                       JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

SingleValueArrayConverter.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace GCRR
{
    internal class SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<ICollection<T>> where T : class, new()
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ICollection<T> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Count == 1 ? (object)value.Single() : value);
        }

        public override ICollection<T> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ICollection<T> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.TokenType switch
            {
                JsonToken.StartObject => new Collection<T> { serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader) },
                JsonToken.StartArray => serializer.Deserialize<ICollection<T>>(reader),
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Converter does not support JSON token type {reader.TokenType}.")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Class/Property using this

```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
    public class WaiverFileWaivers
    {
        [JsonProperty("Waiver")]
        public List<Waiver>? Waivers { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
    public class WaiverFileWaiver:Waiver
    {
        [JsonProperty("Particpants.WaiverParticipant")]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter<WaiverParticipant>))]
        public List<WaiverParticipant>? WaiverParticipants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Waiver
    {
        public string? WaiverID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateSigned { get; set; }
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? SignedName { get; set; }
        public string? SignedNameFirst { get; set; }
        public string? ClientIP { get; set; }
        public string? HasSignature { get; set; }
    }

    public class WaiverParticipant
    {
        public string? ParticipantName { get; set; }
        public string? ParticipantNameFirst { get; set; }
    }
```

JsonPAthConverter works great I can specify the JsonProperty and it finds the location of the array of WaiverParticpiants, the issue though is if it's only 1 it comes back as an object instead of an array of one.  The SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter is supposed to take care of that but you obviously can't do the above and have two Json Converters.

I'm thinking the JsonProperty not only needs to have the path but also to tell it that if it's an object convert it to a list of  (WaiverParticipant in this case)

```
[JsonPropert["Participants.WaiverParticipant", typeof(WaiverParticipant)]
```

I am thinking something like this so if I needed to I could use it for other types where an object comes back instead of an array of 1.

@Andy commented asking for the JSON part of the issue is I don't need all of it and there is a lot of it and it has errors so you can't just deserialize it on top of the fact that if it's returning 1 participant it returns an object vs more then 1 participant it returns an array for that section.  I've updated the classes above so you can see the data I'm after.

Here is the code to deserialize

```
WaiverFileWaiver? waiverFileWaiver = null;
            if (responseContent != null)
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(responseContent)?.SelectToken("Waiver")?.ToString();
                if (json != null)
                    waiverFileWaiver = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaiverFileWaiver>(json);
            }
```

I only care about what's part of the "Waiver" and Participants, so I'll include just that part and I'll remove out some of the JSON that I don't care about leaving only what's in the class that I'm trying to get at.

When there is 1 participant (and yes they spelled Participants missing an "i")

```
"Waiver":
{
    "WaiverID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "DateSigned":"2021-11-15T18:02:51.45",
    "Phone":"8885551212",
    "DOB":"1/1/1753",
    "Email":"noone@redacted.com",
    "SignedName":"LastName",
    "SignedNameFirst":"FirstName",
    "ClientIP":"127.0.0.1",
},
"Particpants":
{
    "WaiverParticipant":
    {
        "ParticipantName":"ParticipantLastName",
        "ParticipantNameFirst":"ParticipantFirstName",
    }
}
```

Where there is 2 or more

```
"Waiver":
{
    "WaiverID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "DateSigned":"2021-11-15T18:02:51.45",
    "Phone":"8885551212",
    "DOB":"1/1/1753",
    "Email":"noone@redacted.com",
    "SignedName":"LastName",
    "SignedNameFirst":"FirstName",
    "ClientIP":"127.0.0.1",
},
"Particpants":
{
    "WaiverParticipant":
    [{
        "ParticipantName":"ParticipantLastName1",
        "ParticipantNameFirst":"ParticipantFirstName1",
    },
    {
        "ParticipantName":"ParticipantLastName2",
        "ParticipantNameFirst":"ParticipantFirstName2",
    }]
}
```

Because I need what JsonPathConverter does to get to the right part of JSON but I also need the Single Object to Array converter as well that is why I need both converters to be as one.  First to fine "Particpants.WaiverParticipant" and also if it's an object make it an array to deserialize into the class and not leave it as an object which causes the error that it can't deserialize an object into an List

I've come up with a solution that works for me but it's not generic so it wouldn't work for anyone else.  If someone knows a way to make this more generic that would be appreciated.

What I did was modify my JasonPathConverter to include for a check on 2 properties that I know sometimes come back as objects and sometimes come back as arrays and when they come back as objects convert them to single object lists and then assign them to the class property.

```
using GCRR.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GCRR
{
#nullable disable
    public class JsonPathConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties()
                                                    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
            {
                JsonPropertyAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                                .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                                                .FirstOrDefault();

                string jsonPath = (att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name);
                JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath);

                if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
                {
                    if (prop.Name == "WaiverParticipants" && token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                    {
                        WaiverParticipant waiverParticipant = token.ToObject<WaiverParticipant>();
                        List<WaiverParticipant> waiverParticipants = new List<WaiverParticipant>
                        {
                            waiverParticipant
                        };
                        prop.SetValue(targetObj, waiverParticipants, null);
                    }
                    else if(prop.Name == "Waivers" && token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                    {
                        Waiver waiver = token.ToObject<Waiver>();
                        List<Waiver> waivers = new List<Waiver>
                        {
                            waiver
                        };
                        prop.SetValue(targetObj, waivers, null);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                        prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return targetObj;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // CanConvert is not called when [JsonConverter] attribute is used
            return false;
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
                                       JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use Newtonsoft JObject it’s a Bit like a Dictionary but with dynamic values.

Comment: Can you show the JSON you are trying to deserialize? People around here love to write custom deserializers.

Comment: @Andy I could but there IS ALOT of it and I only want part of it which is shown in the code above and explained the WaiverParticipant comes back as an object if there is one or an array if there are multiple

Comment: @Andy added some more detail about the classes and part of the JSON to help show the issue.  Both converters work great on their own but I need one that does both.

Comment: What does this do? `[JsonProperty("Particpants.WaiverParticipant")]`? I've been doing this a long, long time and have never seen anything like that.

Comment: @Andy, it using the JsonPathConverter, it tells it where to find the data to serialize for that property very handy when the JSON doesn't match what your class looks like